# I synced my Temple Run 2 to my google account. I reinstalled the game, but I only got some of my saved data back. What should I do?

Tags: temple-run-2

I had to flash my phone. After reinstalling, I linked it to my google account which shows all my progress. But, when I open the game, most of my progress is missing.

Worked really hard on the game !!! Hope someone helps :P !